# Can't mass-assign protected attributes:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I have pulled out all my hair. No more left... :(

I am using Spree 0.3.4, within an extension I need to register some retailers up. so I direct them to a retailers form which has many custom fields which belong to a retailer model...

So I am trying to validate/submit all the fields from one form like so

myextension/app/views/user_registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for (:user, :url => registration_path(@user, :type => "retailer) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :retailer do |r| %>
    <%= r.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

etc etc

```
class Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user

 validates :name,
           :presence => true

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_one :retailer
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :retailer

 attr_accessible :retailer_attributes


 # theres a whole lot more spree and devise stuff here. not sure worth mentioning

end
```

I have also added the abilities in the cancan ability.rb

The problem is the retailer feilds never get validated and the data is never inserted into the database...

I created a blank app, and tried this process from scratch with some plain old scaffolding and it works fine.

any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application helper, do something like this(assuming your have Ruby 1.9.* for the tap functionality, otherwise checkout rails returning [here](http://blakesmith.github.com/2010/08/16/the-rails-returning-statement.html)):

```
  def setup_user(user)
    user.tap do |u|
      u.build_retailer if u.retailer.nil?
    end
  end
```

then in your view change it to this:

```
<%= form_for (setup_user(@user), :url => registration_path(@user, :type => "retailer) do |f| %>
```

See if that works.